# Throwing exception during builder registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to return a http response with 404 code. I have a middleware that catches all exceptions but it does not catch this one because this exception is thrown after the middelware execution and results in internal server error.

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterUserIdProvider(this IServiceCollection builder)
    {
        throw new Exception();
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the `RegisterUserIdProvider` method isn't actually an API endpoint, rather just an extension method used to simplify (and centralise) registering a service. You can't return a 404 if you're not in the context of a HTTP request

Comment: What and where is this `RegisterUserIdProvider` used to? How is your middleware like?